# enum out of range

Tags: c#, enums

What is the best way to handle an invalid enum in my test function. The function is designed to allow for me to compare two items on whether they are compatible with one another or not. Ideally I would like to return false as the result if the index is out of range.

```
public enum VNodeClassID
        {
            Default,
            Apple,
            Orange,
            Grape,
            BlueBerry,
            Watermellon,
            // more items to be added
        }

        // square 2d array
        bool[,] validation = new bool[,] 
        { 
            { false, true, true, false, true, true }, 
            { false, false, true, true, false, true }, 
            { false, true, true, false, true, true }, 
            { false, true, false, true, true, false },
            { false, true, true, true, false, true },
            { false, false, true, false, true, true }
        };

        public void Test()
        {
            var itemA = VNodeClassID.Default;
            var itemB = VNodeClassID.Watermellon;
            bool results = validation[(int)itemA, (int)itemB];

            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}-{2}", results, itemA, itemB);            
        }
```

Comment: Thinking about it again, I might have misunderstood the question. Can you please explain what you mean by "as the result if the index is out of range"?

Comment: You only need to store the `true` values. If it not found then it is a `false`.

Comment: @ja72 I do not believe that would work to do that, I don't know how that would work

Comment: See my answer now for an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a method to return whether the items are compatible, like so:

```
public bool IsCompatible(VNodeClassID itemA, VNodeClassID itemB)
{
    if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(VNodeClassID), itemA))
        return false;

    if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(VNodeClassID), itemB))
        return false;

    return validation[(int)itemA, (int)itemB];
}
```

Then your test method would look like this:

```
public void Test()
{
    var itemA = VNodeClassID.Default;
    var itemB = VNodeClassID.Watermellon;
    bool results = IsCompatible(itemA, itemB);

    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}-{2}", results, itemA, itemB);            
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
var valid_values =
    Enum.GetValues(typeof (VNodeClassID)) //Get all valid values of VNodeClassID
    .Cast<VNodeClassID>()
    .ToList(); 

bool results =
    valid_values.Contains(itemA) && //itemA is within range
    valid_values.Contains(itemB) && //itemB is within range
    validation[(int)itemA, (int)itemB];
```

Answer (score 1):

something like

```
Dictionary<<Tuple<VNodeClassID,VNodeClassID>,bool>>
```

Might be a better approach for type safety and semantic correctness.
Example:

```
   public class ValidKey: Tuple<VNodeClassID, VNodeClassID>
    {
        public ValidKey(VNodeClassID a, VNodeClassID b) : base(a, b) { }
    }


        static Dictionary<ValidKey, bool> validation = new Dictionary<ValidKey, bool>() {
            { new ValidKey(VNodeClassID.Apple, VNodeClassID.Watermellon), true },
            { new ValidKey(VNodeClassID.Apple, VNodeClassID.Orange), true },
            { new ValidKey(VNodeClassID.Orange, VNodeClassID.Grape), true }
        };
        bool Validate(VNodeClassID thing1, VNodeClassID thing2)
        {
            var key = new ValidKey(thing1, thing2);
            return validation.ContainsKey(key) ? validation[key] : false;
        }
```

Usage:

```
   bool a = Validate(VNodeClassID.Apple, VNodeClassID.Watermellon);
   bool b = Validate(VNodeClassID.Grape, VNodeClassID.BlueBerry);
```

Comment: Could you further elaborate how I would do this method

Comment: Sure.  Edited with a more detailed answer.  I know you've accepted an answer, but I think you'll find this one is a bit more robust than using an array for all the reasons you've encountered - casting enums to ints, overflowing, out of range and stuff like that.  It's also nice & simple.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the `[FlagsAttrbute]` and store a dictionary with the bits that correspond to `true`. Something like the code below:

```
[Flags]
public enum VNodeClassID
{
    Default = 0,
    Apple = 1 << 0,         // Apple = 1
    Orange = 1 << 1,        // Orange = 2
    Grape = 1 << 2,         // Grape = 4
    BlueBerry = 1 << 3,     // Bluebery = 8
    Watermellon = 1 << 4,   // Watermelon = 16
    // more items to be added
}

class Program
{
    static Dictionary<VNodeClassID, int> validation = new Dictionary<VNodeClassID, int>();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //{     D      A=1    O=2    G=4    B=8    W=16
        //    { false, true,  true,  false, true,  true },  
        //    { false, false, true,  true,  false, true }, 
        //    { false, true,  true,  false, true,  true }, 
        //    { false, true,  false, true,  true,  false },
        //    { false, true,  true,  true,  false, true },
        //    { false, false, true,  false, true,  true }
        //};
        // set like this
        MakeCompatibe(VNodeClassID.Watermellon,VNodeClassID.Orange|VNodeClassID.BlueBerry|VNodeClassID.Watermellon);
        // or
        validation[VNodeClassID.Default] = 1 + 2 + 8 + 16;
        validation[VNodeClassID.Apple] = 2 + 4 + 16;
        validation[VNodeClassID.Orange] = 1 + 2 + 8 + 16;
        validation[VNodeClassID.Grape] = 1 + 4 + 8;
        validation[VNodeClassID.BlueBerry] = 1 + 2 + 4 + 16;
        validation[VNodeClassID.Watermellon] = 2 + 8 + 16;


        Debug.Assert(CheckCompatibe(VNodeClassID.Apple, VNodeClassID.Watermellon));
        Debug.Assert(!CheckCompatibe(VNodeClassID.Default, VNodeClassID.Grape));
    }

    static void MakeCompatibe(VNodeClassID item, params VNodeClassID[] items)
    {
        int sum = items.Sum((v) => (int)v);
        validation[item] = sum;
    }

    static bool CheckCompatibe(VNodeClassID item, VNodeClassID other)
    {
        if (validation.ContainsKey(item))
        {
            int sum = validation[item];
            return (sum & (int)other) > 0;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

How does it work? Well remember the binary system. Each item in the `enum` represents a `bit` of different values. When combined they create a number, say 27. To check if the bit for 8 for example is set in 27 do an `AND` operation and see if the result is non zero.

```
27 : 00011011
 8 : 00001000  AND
-------------
   : 00001000  CHECK
```

Comment: I've not seen this before . Whats it doing ? 1 << 0,

Comment: @JokerMartini it is the bit shift operator. '1 << n' It takes 1 and multiplies by 2, n times. http://www.dotnetperls.com/shift

Comment: awesome. One last question, what does this translate to? 
        MakeCompatibe(VNodeClassID.Watermellon,VNodeClassID.Orange|VNodeClassID.BlueBerry|VNodeClassID.Watermellon);                                        is that setting Watermellon and orange to be compstile and then blueberry and watermelon to be compatible.  I'm assuming the | is separating the groups of compatibility. Is that correct ?

Comment: I also noticed if i comment out the `validation[VNodeClassID.Default] = 1 + 2 + 8 + 16;
        validation[VNodeClassID.Apple] = 2 + 4 + 16;
        validation[VNodeClassID.Orange] = 1 + 2 + 8 + 16;
        validation[VNodeClassID.Grape] = 1 + 4 + 8;
        validation[VNodeClassID.BlueBerry] = 1 + 2 + 4 + 16;
        validation[VNodeClassID.Watermellon] = 2 + 8 + 16;` and just use the `MakeCompatibe` method, i get a compile error...? why is that.

Comment: The `|` operator is the bitwise `OR` operator. `VNodeClassID.Orange|VNodeClassID.BlueBerry|VNodeClassID.Watermellon = 2+8+16`

Comment: You could also do `MakeCompatibe(VNodeClassID.Watermellon,VNodeClassID.Orange,VNodeClassID.BlueBerry,VNodeClassID.Watermellon);`. This sets one row in the compatibility matrix. You need to supply the others before checking.